# Insert javascript at top of including file in Jinja 2

Tags: python, templates, mako, jinja2, genshi

In Jinja2, I would like the following to work as it looks like it should, by running:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
template = env.get_template('x.html')
print template.render()
```

Essentially the objective is to coalesce all the javascript into the `<head>` tags by using a a `{% call js() %} /* some js */ {% endcall %}` macro.

---

### x.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript>
  {% block head_js %}{% endblock %}
  </script>
  </head>
<body>
  {% include "y.html" %}
</body>
</html>
```

---

### y.html

```
{% macro js() -%}
    // extend head_js
    {%- block head_js -%}
    {{ super() }}
    try { {{ caller() }} } catch (e) {
       my.log.error(e.name + ": " + e.message);
    }
    {%- endblock -%}
{%- endmacro %}

Some ... <div id="abc">text</div> ...

{% call js() %}
    // jquery parlance:
    $(function () {
        $("#abc").css("color", "red");
    });
{% endcall %}
```

---

### Expected result

When I run X.html through jinja2, I would expect the result to be:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript>
  try { {{ $("#abc").css("color", "red"); }} } catch (e) {
       usf.log.error(e.name + ": " + e.message);
    }
  </script>
  </head>
<body>
      Some ... <div id="abc">text</div> ...
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Actual result

The actual results are not encouraging. I get a couple types of potentially illuminating errors, e.g.:

> TypeError: macro 'js' takes no keyword argument 'caller'

or, when I try adding another basis macro such as

```
{% macro js2() -%}
{%- block head_js -%}
//     ... something
{%- endblock -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

I get the following exception

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: block 'head_js' defined twice

I feel as though I am running into a design issue regarding the precedence of the `block` tags over the `macro` tags (i.e. macros do not seem to encapsulate block tags in the way I expect).

---

I suppose my questions are quite simple:

1. Can Jinja2 do what I am attempting? If so, how?
2. If not, is there another Python based templating engine that does support this sort of pattern (e.g. mako, genshi, etc.), which would work without issue in Google App Engine

Thank you for reading - I appreciate your input.

Brian

---

## Edit:

I'm trying to write an extension to resolve this problem. I'm halfway there -- using the following code:

```
from jinja2 import nodes, Environment, FileSystemLoader
from jinja2.ext import Extension

class JavascriptBuilderExtension(Extension):
    tags = set(['js', 'js_content'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(JavascriptBuilderExtension, self).__init__(environment)
        environment.extend(
            javascript_builder_content = [],
        )

    def parse(self, parser):
        """Parse tokens """
        tag = parser.stream.next()
        return getattr(self, "_%s" % str(tag))(parser, tag)

    def _js_content(self, parser, tag):
        """ Return the output """
        content_list = self.environment.javascript_builder_content
        node = nodes.Output(lineno=tag.lineno)
        node.nodes = []

        for o in content_list:
            print "\nAppending node: %s" % str(o)
            node.nodes.extend(o[0].nodes)
        print "Returning node: %s \n" % node
        return node

    def _js(self, parser, tag):
        body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endjs'], drop_needle=True)
        print "Adding: %s" % str(body)
        self.environment.javascript_builder_content.append(body)
        return nodes.Const('<!-- Slurped Javascript -->')

env = Environment(
    loader      = FileSystemLoader('.'),
    extensions  = [JavascriptBuilderExtension],
    )
```

This makes it simple to add Javascript to the end of a template ... e.g.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    {% js %}
    some javascript {{ 3 + 5 }}
    {% endjs %}
    {% js %}
    more {{ 2 }}
    {% endjs %}
    
<script type="text/javascript">
{% js_content %}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Running `env.get_template('x.html').render()` will result in some illuminating comments and the expected output of:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript>
  </script>
  </head>
<body>
    <!-- Slurped Javascript -->
    <!-- Slurped Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    some javascript 8
    more 2
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, this isn't the same as having the script in the head, as hoped, but at least it's conveniently coalesced into one place.

However, the solution is not complete because when you have a `{% include "y.html" %}` in there, where "y.html" includes a `{% js %}` statement, the `{% js_content %}` gets called before the include's `{% js %}` statement (i.e. `x.html` is fully parsed before `y.html` starts).

I also need to, but have not yet, inserted constant nodes that would have the static javascript `try/catch`, which I indicated I wanted to have in there. This is not an issue.

I'm pleased to be making progress, and I'm grateful for input.

I have opened the related question: [Jinja2 compile extension after includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294837/jinja2-compile-extension-after-includes)

---

Comment: Why do you want all the JS in the head?

Comment: @Cameron: Consistency, ease of debugging, and separation of code and content. I'd rather not have hundreds of `<script>` tags littered throughout my HTML.

Comment: @Brian: Fair enough, but I fear there is no simple way to do this... I'm also not sure that you can have blocks inside macros.

Comment: @Cameron: I suspect as much also, but it did strike me as a not entirely undesirable pattern that someone else may have solved already.

Comment: If you would use `extend` instead of `include` you could do it. But because of the full separation between the `parse` and `render` step you won't be able to change the context of the parent scope till after it's too late. Also, the Jinja context is supposed to be immutable.

Comment: That's very helpful. I'm going to try that. If you submit that as an answer, it may be shortly marked correct. ;)

Comment: Incidentally, in `Flask` I use `g` to store the slurped code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my comment:

> If you would use extend instead of
>   include you could do it. But because
>   of the full separation between the
>   parse and render step you won't be
>   able to change the context of the
>   parent scope till after it's too late.
>   Also, the Jinja context is supposed to
>   be immutable.

Example:

**base.html**

```
<html>
   <head>
      {% block head %}

      <title>{% block title %}This is the main template{% endblock %}</title>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      {% block head_js %}
      $(function () {
        $("#abc").css("color", "red");
      });
      {% endblock %}
      </script>

      {% endblock head_js %}
   </head>
   <body>
      {% block body %}
      <h1>{% block body_title %}This is the main template{% endblock body_title %}</h1>

      {% endblock body %}
   </body>
 </html>
```

**some_page.html**

```
{% block title %}This is some page{% endblock title %}

{% block head_js %}
{{ super() }}
try { {{ caller() }} } catch (e) {
   my.log.error(e.name + ": " + e.message);
}        // jquery parlance:
{% endblock head_js %}
```

Comment: @WoLpH: I've marked this the answer, though there is one outstanding issue: how to concatenate a set of nodes extracted from the `parse()` method. Certainly though this is a lot easier of a problem!

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt: You can return a list of nodes from the parse step. `nodes.Template` accepts a list of nodes aswell. You can sum the lists to get one long list of nodes.

Comment: @WoLpH: I figured out the `nodes.CallBack(self.call_method...)`, which will parse everything between the `{% js %}` tags and is accessible in compiled form with the `caller()` argument/function of the called method. What a mouthful. :) You can see it in action in the `_jbc` method of my last edit to the question.

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt: that is true, but the `_jbc` method is not called till the `render()` step. It does give you the output, but in a later step of the entire process. That might not be a problem for you ofcourse :)

Comment: @WoLpH: It just so happens it isn't a problem. :) I use the `environment.jbc` variable post-rendering and do a `string.replace()` for some magic string to-be replaced with the slurped javascript. Mighty cool.

Comment: @WoLpH: It *really* is hacky. lol. But there's a certain crispness about the result that I'm enjoying (until it breaks! haha). :) Thanks for all the help on this set of questions!

Answer (score 2):

You can generalize this into a generic capture extension that works within macros.  Here's one I wrote:

```
from jinja2 import nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension

class CaptureExtension(Extension):
    """
    Generic HTML capture, inspired by Rails' capture helper

    In any template, you can capture an area of content and store it in a global
    variable:

    {% contentfor 'name_of_variable' %}
        blah blah blah 
    {% endcontentfor %}

    To display the result
    {{ name_of_variable }}

    Multiple contentfor blocks will append additional content to any previously 
    captured content.  

    The context is global, and works within macros as well, so it's useful for letting macros define
    javascript or <head> tag content that needs to go at a particular position
    on the base template.

    Inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292630/insert-javascript-at-top-of-including-file-in-jinja-2
    and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html
    """
    tags = set(['contentfor'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(CaptureExtension, self).__init__(environment)

    def parse(self, parser):
        """Parse tokens """
        tag = parser.stream.next()
        args = [parser.parse_expression()]
        body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endcontentfor'], drop_needle=True)
        return nodes.CallBlock(self.call_method('_capture', args),[], [], body).set_lineno(tag.lineno)

    def _capture(self, name, caller):
        if name not in self.environment.globals:
            self.environment.globals[name] = ''
        self.environment.globals[name] += caller()
        return ""
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Lee Semel did not work for me. I think globals are protected from this kind of modification at runtime now.

```
from jinja2 import nodes
import jinja2
from jinja2.ext import Extension

class CaptureExtension(Extension):
    """
    Generic HTML capture, inspired by Rails' capture helper

    In any template, you can capture an area of content and store it in a global
    variable:

    {% capture 'name_of_variable' %}
        blah blah blah 
    {% endcapture %}
    {% capture 'a'  %}panorama{% endcapture %}

    To display the result
    {{ captured['name_of_variable'] }}
    {{ captured['a'] }}

    The context is global, and works within macros as well, so it's useful for letting macros define
    javascript or <head> tag content that needs to go at a particular position
    on the base template.

    Inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292630/insert-javascript-at-top-of-including-file-in-jinja-2
    and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html
    """
    tags = set(['capture'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(CaptureExtension, self).__init__(environment)
        assert isinstance(environment, jinja2.Environment)
        self._myScope = {}
        environment.globals['captured'] = self._myScope

    def parse(self, parser):
        """Parse tokens """
        assert isinstance(parser, jinja2.parser.Parser)
        tag = parser.stream.next()
        args = [parser.parse_expression()]
        body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endcapture'], drop_needle=True)
        return nodes.CallBlock(self.call_method('_capture', args),[], [], body).set_lineno(tag.lineno)

    def _capture(self, name, caller):
        self._myScope[name] = caller()
        return ""
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers above *nearly* answered my query (I wanted to put disparate bits of JavaScript all in one place - the bottom), accept using the '+=' variety which appends captures to each other caused problems on refresh.  The capture would end up with multiple copies of everything and caused all sorts of issues depending on how many times refresh was hit.

I worked around this by using the line number of the tag in a dictionary to ensure captures are only done once.  The one minor disadvantage of this approach is the global needs to be rebuilt every time a capture tage is encountered.

Works well for me though.

```
from jinja2 import Markup, nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension

class CaptureExtension(Extension):
    tags = set(['capture'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(CaptureExtension, self).__init__(environment)
        environment.globals['captured'] = {}
        self._captured = {}

    def parse(self, parser):
        lineno = next(parser.stream).lineno
        args = [parser.parse_expression(), nodes.Const(lineno)]
        body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endcapture'], drop_needle=True)
        return nodes.CallBlock(self.call_method('_capture', args), [], [], body).set_lineno(lineno)

    def _capture(self, name, lineno, caller):
        if name not in self._captured:
            self._captured[name] = {}
        self._captured[name][lineno] = caller()
        markup = Markup(''.join(s for s in self._captured[name].values()))
        self.environment.globals['captured'][name] = markup
        return ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class JavascriptBuilderExtension(Extension):
    tags = set(['js'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(JavascriptBuilderExtension, self).__init__(environment)
        environment.extend(jbc = "",)

    def parse(self, parser):
        """Parse tokens """
        tag = parser.stream.next()
        body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endjs'], drop_needle=True)
        return nodes.CallBlock(
            self.call_method('_jbc', [], [], None, None),
            [], [], body
        ).set_lineno(tag.lineno)

    def _jbc(self, caller=None):
        self.environment.jbc += "\ntry { %s } catch (e) { ; };" % caller()
        return "<!-- Slurped -->"
```

After completed, the environment will contain a variable `jbc` that has all the Javascript. I can insert this via, for example, `string.Template`.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4292630/4) to the question [Insert javascript at top of including file in Jinja 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292630/insert-javascript-at-top-of-including-file-in-jinja-2) by the OP [Brian M. Hunt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19212/brian-m-hunt) under CC BY-SA 2.5.</sub>