# Jinja2 compile extension after includes

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

In Jinja2, is it possible to have a `Node` from the AST render after all `include` statements have completed?

This is a key [piece of a solution to a bigger puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292630/insert-javascript-at-top-of-including-file-in-jinja-2).

Example code:

### x.py

```
from jinja2 import nodes, Environment, FileSystemLoader
from jinja2.ext import Extension

class XExtension(Extension):
    tags = set(['x', 'get_x'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(XExtension, self).__init__(environment)
        environment.extend(
            x = 0,
        )

    def parse(self, parser):
        tag = parser.stream.next()
        return getattr(self, "_%s" % str(tag))(parser, tag)

   def _get_x(self, parser, tag):
        """ Return the output """
        return nodes.Const(self.environment.x)

   def _x(self, parser, tag):
        """ Add an x """
        self.environment.x += 1
        return nodes.Const('<!-- Adding an X -->')

env = Environment(
    loader      = FileSystemLoader('.'),
    extensions  = [XExtension],
    )

template = env.get_template('x.html')
print template.render()
```

### x.html

```
Xx {% x %} Xx {% x %}
{% include "y.html" %}
Xs xes: {% get_x %}
```

### y.html

```
Yx {% x %}
Ys xes: {% get_x %}
```

The output is

```
Xx <!-- Adding an X --> Xx <!-- Adding an X -->
Yx <!-- Adding an X -->
Ys xes:3
Xs xes 2
```

How may it be possible to have `Xs xes` count the X's in `y.html`, which is the behaviour I desire and expect?

In other words, is there a way to delay the parsing or flattening to text returned from the `_get_x()` in `x.html`?

Thank you very much for reading.

Kind regards,

Brian

Comment: It was a good idea separating this into another question, the first one was getting rather long ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jinja2 does streaming of template data.  The template is evaluated instruction for instruction into a stream of smaller strings that gets concatenated into an actual unicode string by the `render()` method.  However you can also get hold of the stream by calling into `generate()` instead of `render()`.

With some in-band signalling and postprocessing of the stream one might probably be able to implement something like that, but it's against the way of how Jinja2 was designed so it might break horribly and is totally unsupported.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It may be of assistance if I were able to `jinja2.compiler.generator` or equivalently process a list of `Output` nodes to unicode (i.e. nodes not encapsulated in a `Template` node) -- I'd be grateful to know if there is a straightforward way to do this.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I think if you want to continue go down that road, the Environment callback functions for streaming and pre/postprocessing are probably more of a help than the actual compiler interface.  The reason for this is that what you try to do has to happen on a different level than the compilation which has to undergo certain rules.

Comment: Thanks, Armin. I have an extension that extracts nodes, and I wish to save those nodes to the current environment, then render them into unicode after the current template completes rendering. What I seek is along the lines of a function like `Environment.render(nodes) -> unicode` where `nodes` is a list of (non-Template) nodes slurped by the extension and saved to the Environment. Alternatively, I would like to either save the rendered nodes to the environment during processing, or convert them back to source to be rendered independently.

Comment: I've opened a new question, that I hope clarifies the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309266